# How to add new custom element to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2 and trying to learn. I find the documentation a little tough so I am hoping someone can help me understand better/point me in the right direction.

I understand how to override theme files but one thing I can't figure out is how to add something that does not yet exist. I want to create a conditional modal box that prompts the user to an action. I need markup, javascript and styles.

Can somebody help me figure out how to add this custom element to Magento, where to place these new files in the file structure and anything that needs to be done to conditionally display this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Theme files (.phtml) are always connected to a Block (.php). You need to learn how to override Magento blocks if you want to add php methods.

It's the same for Models (database handlers) and Controllers (http response handlers).

[Magento 2 php rewrites](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/)

---

2/ To add styles and javascript files, you have to learn `Magento layouts`. Thoses are xml files, defining Magento pages structure.

[Magento 2 layouts](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-layouts-blocks-templates/)

---

3/ To rewrite existing javascript file you'll use `requirejs-config.js` file. You will have to learn using `require js` and `knockout js`.

[Javascript bulding in Magento 2](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/javascript-bundling-magento-2/)

---

In conclusion, you have a world to learn.

**Stay motivated and passionate, take the time to learn and you will progress.**